# setEntities compared to updateEntities and addEntities

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand ngneat/elf-entities better and I have come across these 3 methods that confuses me a bit.

```
public set(tanks: Tank[]) {
   store.update(setEntities(tanks));
}

public update(tank: Tank) {
   store.update(updateEntities(tank.tankNumber, tank));}

  public add(tank: Tank) {
store.update(addEntities(tank));}
```

As far as I understand setEntities updates/adds multiple "tanks",
while updateEntities only update a single entity.
While addEntities adds a single entity.

I have a specific use case where I want to add a "tank" if it doesn't exist and if it does then update it. If I use add and it already exists then I get an error, and if I call update when the store is empty then nothing happens. I only have a single entity so I cant call set method.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: https://ngneat.github.io/elf/docs/features/entities-management/entities/#mutations

`setEntities`:
Replace current collection with the provided collection

`addEntities`:
Add an entity or entities to the store

`updateEntities`:
Update an entity or entities in the store

`upsertEntities`:
Add or update entities.

So... setEntities will remove everything from the collection. And will add only the entities you put as parameter. This is good for a reset or something similar. I doubt you'd like to use that often.

If you want to update existing entities, or create them if they do not exist, use upsertEntities. This will only create the entity if it does not exist yet, update it otherwise.